# Unix wildcard selectors? (Asterisks)

Tags: unix

In Ryan Bates' [Railscast about git](http://railscasts.com/episodes/96-git-on-rails), his *.gitignore* file contains the following line:

`tmp/**/*`

What is the purpose of using the double asterisks followed by an asterisk as such: `**/*`?
Would using simply `tmp/*` instead of `tmp/**/*` not achieve the exact same result?

Googling the issue, I found an unclear IBM article about it, and I was wondering if someone could clarify the issue.

Comment: Note: While some shells support this syntax, Git does not. In a `.gitignore` file this is equivalent to `tmp/*/*`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It says to go into all the subdirectories below tmp, as well as just the content of tmp.

e.g. I have the following:

```
$ find tmp
tmp
tmp/a
tmp/a/b
tmp/a/b/file1
tmp/b
tmp/b/c
tmp/b/c/file2
```

matched output:

```
$ echo tmp/*
tmp/a tmp/b
```

matched output:

```
$ echo tmp/**/*
tmp/a tmp/a/b tmp/a/b/file1 tmp/b tmp/b/c tmp/b/c/file2
```

It is a default feature of zsh, to get it to work in bash 4, you perform:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: Is there nomenclature for this kind of pattern matching in Unix? I'm trying to find more information and I don't know how to Google it.

Comment: Pattern matching for files is called globbing. The basic variants are `*` for 0 or more characters, `?` for any character and `[CharacterRange]` for characters matching a particular range e.g. `[0-9]` to match a digit. Some shells extend it in their own ways, which includes the `**` syntax.

Comment: I tried it in my bash shell but echo tmp/**/* and tmp/*/* give the same result, so I don't see ** doing anything more than *

Comment: Make more than two level of subdirectories and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

From http://blog.privateergroup.com/2010/03/gitignore-file-for-android-development/:

(kwoods)

```
"The double asterisk (**) is not a git thing per say, it’s really a linux / Mac shell thing.

It would match on everything including any sub folders that had been created.

You can see the effect in the shell like so:

# ls ./tmp/* = should show you the contents of ./tmp (files and folders)
# ls ./tmp/** = same as above, but it would also go into each sub-folder and show the contents there as well."
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation of gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), this syntax is supported since git version 1.8.2.

Here is the relevant section:

> Two consecutive asterisks (`**`) in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading `**` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere, the
>     same as pattern `foo`. `**/foo/bar` matches file or directory `bar`
>     anywhere that is directly under directory `foo`.
> - A trailing `/**` matches everything inside. For example, `abc/**` matches all files inside directory `abc`, relative to the location of
>     the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, `a/**/b` matches `a/b`,
>     `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on.
> - Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.