# How to use PyYAML to parse YAML files?

Tags: parsing, yaml, pyyaml

I just managed to install PyYAML...but I'm still not sure how to parse yaml files by using PyYAML (Sorry for my poor programming knowledge)..

Actually my real intention is to parse/validate YAML files to make sure they're following the right syntax...

So the instructions I found is here http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML, but I'm still confused about how to use it, especially for testing several documents (not pasting contents from the yaml files)..

Can you help explain it? Thank you very much!

Penny

Comment: Did you see my answer on your previous question? It uses Ruby but gets the job done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150923/bulk-validating-yaml-files

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you Jordan! I managed to parse yaml files by using node.js, which is awesome! But the link that you provided is very useful...I'm wondering if we can use those codes to parse files in a directory instead of one by one?